# How to make the toolbar and tabs-bar of qterminal dark?

Tags: terminal, colors, fonts, gtk, qt

[image: White and ugly]

It looks ugly. How can i fix it.`Terminal` has good dark style. [image: terminal nice]

Also , ubuntu regular font is not available in preferences of `terminal` but its installed. Any idea how to fix qterminal along with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QTerminal is a Qt application, thus you need to apply a dark Qt theme in order to get a dark toolbar and tab bars.

This could be done using LXQt Appearance: [Lxqt: what are the Qt-themes/Widget Styles, and how to install new ones?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/468709/lxqt-what-are-the-qt-themes-widget-styles-and-how-to-install-new-ones)

Answer (score 4):

For me installing adwaita and restarting qterminal allowed me to select a dark widget theme in the preferences:

```
sudo apt install adwaita-qt
```